# CSS an image is displayed super small in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I noticed today a strange behavior of Firefox, which I can not explain. An element (img) which is inside a div box and has a height : 50% will not be half the size of the parent.

[image: firefox view]

Instead it has a size of only 2 - 3 px (the parent is at least 80px high at my resolution). In Chrome everything is displayed as expected.

[image: chrome view]

HTML Code:

[image: html code]

CSS:

[image: css of image]
[image: css of parent]

Have also searched for this behavior on google. The only thing I found was a firefox setting (about:config browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing) for automatic scaling of graphics. But this did not fix the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this public? Can you share the link? Otherwise at least include the html and css code to your question.